# Limit MongoDB aggregation $lookup to only 1 match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

There are two collections, `users` and `reports`.

My goal is to make an aggregation that gets all users and for each `user` includes the amount of user's **last** `report`.

Here is my current aggregation:

```
db.users.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'reports',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'userId',
    as: 'report',
  },
}, {
  $project: {
    'lastReportAmount': {
      $let: {
        vars: {
          lastReport: {'$arrayElemAt': ['$report', 0]},
        },
        in: '$$lastReport.amount',
      },
    },
    'id': '$_id',
    'name': 1,
    'firstLogin': 1,
    'email': 1,
  },
}])
```

This query works correctly, BUT it's very slow.
The reason for that is that `$lookup` returns **all** reports that match a certain `userId`, instead of one (last).

**Is there a way to limit the `$lookup` to only one match?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the new lookup variant available in 3.6.

Add an index on the userId and date field in reports collection and see if it gets picked up.

```
db.users.aggregate([
 {"$lookup":{
    "from": "reports",
    "let": {"_id":"$_id"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$$_id","$userId"]}}},
      {"$sort":{"date": -1}},
      {"$limit":1}
    ],
    "as": "lookup-latest"
 }},
 {"$project": {
    'lastReportAmount':{'$arrayElemAt':['$lookup-latest', 0]},
    'id': '$_id',
    'name': 1,
    'firstLogin': 1,
    'email': 1
 }}
])
```