# MongoDB aggregation limit matches to 1 of each

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use MongoDB aggregation get values that are in the `idArray` but doesn't exist as a doc:

```
 idArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

docs

```
     {node: "a", value: "3"}
     {node: "c", value: "3"}
     {node: "a", value: "1"}
     {node: "a", value: "4"}

   db.docs.aggregate([
      {$match:
        node: 
          $in: idArray}
      {$group: {"_id":null , "matches":{$addToSet:"$node"}} } 
      {$project:
        node_not_found: { $setDifference: [ INPUT_ARRAY, "$matches" ] }
        _id: 0}
    ]).each (err, node) ->
```

This should produce:

```
{ "node_not_found" : [ "b" ] }
```

My issue is that this is quite slow as it matches `a` multiple times and tries to push it all into the array. How do I limit the match to have only 1 of a so that duplicate work isn't done?

Comment: why you want to get set difference from query in last $project stage? you can do it after query nodejs side, and also i would suggest you can do $gurop operation in you nodejs side,  second create [single field index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/) on `node` field it will be little faster, third you can use `$addToSet` instead of `$push` operator in $group stage. it will manage unique element in array.

Comment: @turivishal thanks, I tend to assume it would be faster to do it in the db since the db would be optimized for it? But that may not be true. Your advice is to do it client side then? The question still really is about limiting the matches though. I would like to learn how to do that even if there are optimizations elsewhere.

Comment: This exists, but I don't quite understand what it's about or how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429054/limit-mongodb-aggregation-lookup-to-only-1-match

Comment: *Your advice is to do it client side then?* yes because array operations in query would be heavy, and in your last comment link that is a 2 collection and they want to join using reference but in our case we have single collection right? 1) for optimization you can create an index on `node` field 2) use $addToSet instead $push, 3) do your last stage in client side.

Comment: I usually avoid writing heavy database queries and aggregations, because then I lose the ability to cache intermediate results. It's far easier to scale a service than it is to scale a database.

Comment: @turivishal I do have an index, so there's no way to limit the match then? I'll make those changes, thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How do I limit the match to have only 1*

I don't think there is better way to limit document in match stage using `$in` query.

> *My issue is that this is quite slow as it matches*

You need to avoid such array operations from your query,

- remove last `$project` stage and do that operation in your client side,
- create [single field index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/) on `node` field, it will be more effective for performance,
- i am suggesting below query, i have not tested it but you can try may be it will help,

**Suggestion 1:**

```
  { $match: { node: { $in: ["a", "b", "c"] } } },
  { $group: { "_id": "$node" } }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/14mtD1C2oJ6)

Result:

```
[{ "_id": "c" }, { "_id": "a" }]
```

**Suggestion 2:**

```
  { $match: { node: { $in: ["a", "b", "c"] } } },
  { $group: { "_id": null, "matches": { $addToSet: "$node" } } }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WU8H_GNDCK8)

Result:

```
[{ "_id": null, "matches": ["c", "a"] }]
```

Other stuff you can do in your client side code.

You can check state of your query using [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html#examples), see the examples and you can try in your query like  `db.docs.explain().aggregate(..)` it will provide each statistics of your query stages.